# Get number of commits per author on all branches of Git repo

Tags: git, github

I used `git shortlog -sn --all` to get a list of all authors with their commits for all the branches.

The problem is , i just want the list of authors that have been contributing since last year , ignoring the others. Is there any way to include a time range in this? Because from the help page i don't see anything like that.

The git-hub also provides this through API call but that just returns the top 100 contributors, not all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the since argument for this.

`git shortlog -sn --all --since=1.year`

It has relative times but you can also use dates:

`git shortlog -sn --all --since={2016-01-01}`

Or a range:

`git shortlog -sn --all --after={2013-04-01} --before={2014-01-01}`

Comment: Hi , thanks alot for quick reply , this was not mentioned in shortlog --help page. Can you please update the answer with getting user ID rather than full name? For some users it is showing full names , for some it shows just First name.

Comment: @IjazKhan I'm looking at the docs at the mo and I don't believe it's possible. The `pretty="%aE"` option shows the author's email but it doesn't work in conjunction with the `-s` summary flag.